# Extending GWT's Widget Class

Tags: java, gwt, textbox, label, widget

I'm making a new class called 'Cell' which extends the GWT Widget class. The purpose of this class is to be a cell in a spreadsheet -- it therefore must be able to switch between being a GWT Label object and a GWT TextBox object.

The only way that I can think of doing this is by making Cell extend Widget and include a private Widget called 'cell' which I can store the current Label or TextBox object with. Like so...

```
public class Cell extends Widget {

private Widget cell;

...

}
```

Unfortunately, this solution is not ideal because if I want Cell to fully operate like a Widget, I will have override Widget's methods to point to my inner 'cell' Widget. Is there a more elegant way of creating a Cell Widget which can be either a Label or TextBox?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not extend Composite instead of extending Widget?

```
public class Cell extends Composite {
    private Label label;
    private TextBox textBox;
    private SomeContainerWidget container;

   ...
}
```

Just add/remove the `label` or the `textBox` widget to the `container` as needed.

Using composite is the more elegant way as you do not expose the entire Widget interface, but only the methods needed for your spreadsheet cell.

Checkout [this section](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomWidgets.html) from GWT docs for building custom widgets for more information.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot, I just started looking at GWT and wasn't aware of this class.

Comment: What if I can't extend Composite?

Comment: Could you provide some more details on why you can't extend Composite?