# how can i make the first character of my textbox constant or fixed

Tags: java, gwt

I have a textbox for taking Amount i.e  $100.

My textboxes already have a $ sign in them:

```
<g:TextBox ui:field="fee">$</g:TextBox>
```

What i want is that a user can never delete/edit $ sign inside my textBox and can only enter amount after that $ sign,

Is this possible?

Comment: You can create a custom component. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082864/extending-gwts-widget-class

Comment: Basically you have to use script to control this. Each time the text box is changed, verify if the leading $ is there or not, if not, add it necessarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work using events

```
button.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
  public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
    TextBox b = (TextBox)event.getSource();
    if (!b.getValue().startsWith("$")) {
      b.setValue("$" + b.getValue());
    }
  }
});
```

Although a solution based on css should look and perform better:

Put a lavel with the $ symbol over the input box.

```
Label l = new Label("$");
TextBox b = new TextBox();
l.getElement().addClassName("dollarlabel");
b.getElement().addClassName("dollarinput");
RootPanel.get().add(b);
RootPanel.get().add(l);
```

and some css styling

```
.dollarlabel {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
.dollarinput {
  margin-left: -10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd better put the `$` as a label outside the textbox. If you want to make it appear as if it's within the textbox, you can style the `<span>`, `<div>` or `<label>` that encloses the `$` and the textbox with a frame, and remove the border of the textbox. And using [UiBinder I18N](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinderI18n), you can easily move the currency label on either side of the box.

FYI, this is what Google does in the GMail, Reader and Groups search boxes for the drop-down button.

Something like:

```
<ui:style>
  .container {
    border: 1px solid gray;
  }
  .inputbox {
    border: none;
  }
</ui:style>
<g:HTMLPanel tag="label" addStyleNames="{style.container}">
   <ui:msg>
     $
     <ui:ph name="inputbox"><g:TextBox addStyleNames="{style.inputbox}" /></ui:ph>
   </ui:msg>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

And a locale could define the message as, say, `{0} €` to put a `€` on the right of the input box.